# no result with shell_exec

Tags: php, shell-exec

I'm trying to run a shell command inside a PHP script which works in the terminal but doesn't in my PHP application.

This command

```
$ cp /path/to/file /another/path/to/file
```

works with in PHP with this line:

```
<?php shell_exec('cp /path/to/file /another/path/to/file') ?>
```

So `shell_exec` works in general.

Unfortunately this command

```
$ jpegtran -copy none -optimize -outfile /another/path/to/file /path/to/file
```

**doesn't** work witin PHP:

```
<?php shell_exec('jpegtran -copy none -optimize -outfile /another/path/to/file /path/to/file') ?>
```

Comment: `su` the same user that your web server runs as, for instance, `su www-data`. can you execute `jpegtran`? if not, consider adjusting permissions accordingly.

Comment: How can I change permission on `jpegtran`?

Comment: Add `www-data` (or your apache user) to the sudoer's group. This can be dangerous though, so be absolutely sure that you are safe.

Comment: Don't do what was suggested above; instead, make a new group and add your apache user to that group, and your CLI user(s). then change the ownership to that group, so you protect your sudoers.

Comment: Current user in PHP is `Xaver:staff` where `Xaver` is my user

Comment: as mentioned by @Ohgodwhy create another group for user Xaver as he is currently in the staff group...

you need to make a new group and assign Xaver to this new group which then gives him permission to access the jpegtran